# WPF Printing - XPSDocumentWriter Behaves Different on Windows 8.1 vs Windows 7

Tags: wpf, printing, windows-7, windows-8.1, xps

We have a .NET 4.0 / WPF application that needs to print potentially huge documents (in excess of 5000 pages). The solution we currently have developed works wonderfully on Windows 7 but the exact same application, running on Windows 8.1, fails with an "Out of Memory" exception at 1500-2000 pages.

On Windows 7:

- We have tested to 20,000 pages plus with no issues
- Application memory use stays nearly constant during printing
- No additional files are created in the Temp folder during printing
- We can see the print job spooling to the selected printer at the same time we are printing from our application

On Windows 8.1, running the *exact* same code:

- Application memory grows linearly during printing and frequently crashes the application with an "Out of Memory" exception.
- A .XPS file is created in the Temp folder during printing, apparently containing the document we are printing
- (when the app doesn't crash) There is no print spooler activity until *after* we reach the end of the printing process

The behavior on Windows 8.1 is the same regardless of which printer we select (typically we use either the Adobe PDF driver or Primo PDF, but we also use "real" printers of various flavors).

Are there known differences in WPF printing under Windows 8.1 that we need to account for in our code?

The following code sample roughly encapsulates our process (though the DrawingVisual is different for each page) -- essentially, we create one DrawingVisual per page and write each one to an VisualsToXpsDocument instance.

In my testing, this sample runs to completion on Windows 7 but fails at about 2000 pages on Windows 8.1:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    LocalPrintServer server = new LocalPrintServer();
    PrintQueueCollection queueCollection = server.GetPrintQueues(new[] { EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local, EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections });

    var printQueue = queueCollection.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Name == "PrimoPDF");

    // set the job name so print to file (i.e. pdf) has a default name to use
    printQueue.CurrentJobSettings.Description = "Testing 1 2 3";

    var validationResult = printQueue.MergeAndValidatePrintTicket(printQueue.UserPrintTicket, printQueue.DefaultPrintTicket);

    var printTicket = validationResult.ValidatedPrintTicket;

    var writer = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(printQueue);

    var visualsToXpsDocumentCollator = writer.CreateVisualsCollator();


    var visual = GetVisual();

    visualsToXpsDocumentCollator.BeginBatchWrite();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; ++i)
    {
        visualsToXpsDocumentCollator.Write(visual, printTicket);
        Console.WriteLine("Printed page " + i);
    }
    visualsToXpsDocumentCollator.EndBatchWrite();
}

private static DrawingVisual GetVisual()
{
    DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();

    using (DrawingContext dc = visual.RenderOpen())
    {
        // Create formatted text--in a particular font at a particular size
        FormattedText ft = new FormattedText(
            @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei at elitr legimus apeirian, ea sit bonorum alienum neglegentur, docendi minimum adolescens mei te. Ex alii euismod argumentum mel, voluptua ponderum euripidis cum id, alii efficiendi appellantur per et. Prompta nusquam ea mea. Putent labores id vim, eos ullum vivendum contentiones cu. In eos eius facilisis comprehensam.  Percipit lucilius repudiare vis in, id per singulis omittantur. Qui vocent vivendo ad. Mollis vidisse habemus pri ne. Est voluptaria referrentur an, vivendum indoctum vel an. Mea vitae referrentur cu.  Ridens quidam fuisset et nam, lorem vocibus ut duo, natum prodesset in vix. Vix no sonet consequuntur, per inermis omittam referrentur in. Posse voluptatum has et. Quando lucilius eam in, ex his sint consulatu ullamcorper. Id mel utroque postulant.  No has regione facilisi deserunt. Te quidam postulant mea. Usu in primis semper. Utamur probatus ad est. Quo at quis eripuit, sed assum putent id. Te probatus omittantur necessitatibus quo, at vel probo facer efficiendi, tota denique interesset vix et. Ei sit hinc argumentum, saperet dolorem habemus sit no.  Ea essent aliquip postulant est, ad oratio evertitur duo. Scripta scriptorem ea est. Nec ut duis complectitur. Ut eos vide doming, nam id iudicabit dissentias, eos duis putent no.  Tempor pertinacia referrentur eum cu, meis harum homero eum id. An eius repudiare eum, quo assum lucilius ad. Consulatu molestiae ius ei, te elit assum erroribus usu, an his choro quodsi. In nam unum fabellas, mei ad deseruisse moderatius intellegam. Id utroque ancillae nec, mea sale mollis perfecto te. Eu vis dicant delenit convenire, magna mandamus urbanitas ius ea. Ne dolor prompta mentitum sit.  Id veritus consequat sit. Sententiae incorrupte et has, quod affert voluptua pri ut. Vel enim meis ancillae et, est te vidisse malorum. Nec facilis commune ut, ut est impetus convenire. An cum tollit suscipit accommodare, ius eu labore placerat, mollis contentiones ei eam. Novum mazim id cum, dolores molestiae quo ei. Ex eos tollit consequat, sed ei epicuri perfecto.  Eum at nihil clita albucius, propriae prodesset eu vel, id pri eruditi debitis appareat.",
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
            FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
            new Typeface(new FontFamily("Century"), FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Bold, FontStretches.Normal),
            24, Brushes.Black);

        ft.MaxTextWidth = 750;

        // Draw the text at a location
        dc.DrawText(ft, new Point(10.0, 10.0));
    }
    return visual;
}
```

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions as to what we might want to look for or change.

Comment: A large portion of the windows printing subsystem changed between windows 7 and windows 8. The temporary .xps file and delayed print spooler activity are a direct result of these changes. Is your app 64 bit? That may help alleviate the problem.

Comment: Given the load your app is putting on the system, can I assume you are allowed to alter the print queue properties? You may find that changing the spooling options on the advanced tab to direct printing may help as well.

Comment: Tried changing the spooling options to print direct but there was no effect. Still creates the .XPS temp file.